# Create a function that returns the total number of smiley faces

Tags: ruby

I've been working on a task to create a function that returns the total number of smiley faces. Valid smiley faces look like: ":) :D ;-D :~)" and invalid smiling faces: ";( :> :} :] ".

So far this is how my answer looks:

```
def count_smileys(arr)
  arr.to_s.count(":)", ":D", ";-D", ":~")
end
```

The only positive test my code returns:

```
Test Passed: Value == 0
```

```
Expected: 4, instead got: 0
Expected: 2, instead got: 0
Expected: 1, instead got: 0
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation for `String#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-count) says, each individual argument to `String#count` defines a set of characters, and the final set of characters to count is the intersection of all those sets.

In your case, the intersection is empty, therefore you are counting nothing:

- `:)` is the set { `:`, `)` }
- `:D` is the set { `:`, `D` }
- `;-D` is the set of characters starting with `;` and ending with `D`, i.e. { `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` }
- `:~` is the set { `:`, `~` }

So, the intersection of all of those sets is

- { `:`, `)` } ∩ { `:`, `D` } ∩ { `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` } ∩ { `:`, `~` }
- = { `:` } ∩ { `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` } ∩ { `:`, `~` }
- = ∅ ∩ { `:`, `~` }
- = ∅

i.e. the empty set.

Comment: Thank you for the details break down mate

Answer (score 1):

Very good answer by Jörg.

To also provide a possible solution. You don't need to cast this to a string, as array also has a count method which accepts a block.

```rb
def count_smileys(arr)
  array.count do |element|
   [":)", ":D", ";-D", ":~"].include?(element)
  end
end
```

https://makandracards.com/makandra/31141-ruby-counting-occurrences-of-an-item-in-an-array-enumerable

Comment: this was very clear and concise, also just had a read through the link, really appreciated mate, thanks!